# Instead of opening a new page in the current window, Selenium opens new tabs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

After lick on the button new url(/app/admin/directories) should be open in the current screen, but in my case, after click on the button some new browser tabs are opening with new url(/app/admin). It's ok for firefox, but have issue for chrome.

```
ChromeDriver 107.0.5304.62
Selenium-java 4.5.3
Windows 10, os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0'
java.version: '19'
```

I was trying to check the same with old chrome driver + browser, old selenium - but got the same result.

Selenium log:

```
   "button": "none",
   "buttons": 0,
   "clickCount": 0,
   "force": 0.0,
   "modifiers": 2,
   "pointerType": "mouse",
   "tangentialPressure": 0.0,
   "tiltX": 0,
   "tiltY": 0,
   "twist": 0,
   "type": "mouseMoved",
   "x": 132,
   "y": 470
}
[1667288869.031][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Input.dispatchMouseEvent (id=1704) (session_id=E2411BC3ECA1AFDAF681B611374DB4E6) B30565F7D055633A197C6ACB11517C0D {
   "button": "left",
   "buttons": 0,
   "clickCount": 1,
   "force": 0.0,
   "modifiers": 2,
   "pointerType": "mouse",
   "tangentialPressure": 0.0,
   "tiltX": 0,
   "tiltY": 0,
   "twist": 0,
   "type": "mousePressed",
   "x": 132,
   "y": 470
}
[1667288869.032][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Input.dispatchMouseEvent (id=1705) (session_id=E2411BC3ECA1AFDAF681B611374DB4E6) B30565F7D055633A197C6ACB11517C0D {
   "button": "left",
   "buttons": 1,
   "clickCount": 1,
   "force": 0.0,
   "modifiers": 2,
   "pointerType": "mouse",
   "tangentialPressure": 0.0,
   "tiltX": 0,
   "tiltY": 0,
   "twist": 0,
   "type": "mouseReleased",
   "x": 132,
   "y": 470
}
[1667288869.035][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Input.dispatchMouseEvent (id=1703) (session_id=E2411BC3ECA1AFDAF681B611374DB4E6) B30565F7D055633A197C6ACB11517C0D {
}
[1667288869.068][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Input.dispatchMouseEvent (id=1704) (session_id=E2411BC3ECA1AFDAF681B611374DB4E6) B30565F7D055633A197C6ACB11517C0D {
}
[1667288869.259][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.frameScheduledNavigation (session_id=E2411BC3ECA1AFDAF681B611374DB4E6) B30565F7D055633A197C6ACB11517C0D {
   "delay": 0,
   "frameId": "B30565F7D055633A197C6ACB11517C0D",
   "reason": "anchorClick",
   "url": "https://MY-APP/app/admin"
}
[1667288869.260][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.frameRequestedNavigation (session_id=E2411BC3ECA1AFDAF681B611374DB4E6) B30565F7D055633A197C6ACB11517C0D {
   "disposition": "newTab",
   "frameId": "B30565F7D055633A197C6ACB11517C0D",
   "reason": "anchorClick",
   "url": "https://MY-APP/app/admin"
}
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried.

Comment: this is probably due to a link target...  (if the target is set to a name of a frame that doesn't exist, chrome will open a new tab/window.... firefox doesn't do that... I think it'll open in the current active frame.)  Include the html markup of the link you are clicking, and probably the frames/iframes on the page.